# Laravel 4: DB::transaction offer a callback to see result

Tags: php, transactions, laravel, laravel-4

i am using the DB::transaction within a project all works fine, but what i am doing first is creating a folder:

```
  $folder = \File:: makeDirectory($path, perm, recur);
```

then on passing this i then init my DB::transaction:

```
  if($folder){
    \DB::transaction(function() use($folderName){
        /////--- do the db stuff in here.

   })
  } else {
    ///-- folder creation failed return message
  }
```

This is all good but if my folder is created then the DB::transaction fails, there is no way for me to know this so i can then remove the folder created and then inform the user that the current process failed.

Any ideas how i can get a callback type so that if it fails then remove folder, i have tried a try catch but with laravels own errors take over, and it does not get that far?

SO how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the transaction fails, an exception will be thrown. You simply catch it:

```
$folder = \File:: makeDirectory($path, perm, recur);

if($folder){
  try
  {
    \DB::transaction(function() use($folderName){
      /////--- do the db stuff in here.
    })
  }
  catch (\Exception $e)
  {
    /////--- DB STUFF FAILED

    // TODO: DELETE FOLDER

    throw $e;
  }

} else {
  ///-- folder creation failed return message
}
```

EDIT: See laravel's source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a4c76fb3601ee75a23dc0aec3f1a7fde86faf91d/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L415

Comment: The problem here I have tried a try/catch and before it can call my failure it initiates laravels exception call to the attempt as in that link its covered by its own try/catch so does the file class

Comment: not sure but copied what you had above and it seemed to have worked, strange but thanks

Comment: It was the Exception's namespace. Note the backlash before it. :)